# URL being encoded wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I'm getting confused passing the `http://` in a string to the url as it is being stripped to

```
http%3A%2F%2F
```

I tried.. using the encodeURIComponent(http://)

but that didn't work either..
I'm trying to pass the url into here:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?url=
```

Here is my code that isn't working:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fb', function(e) {

var findfb = $('.fb').parent().parent().parent().find(".zoomy").attr("src");

var facebook_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=http://www.site.com/folder1/'+encodeURIComponent(findfb)+
  '&amp;title='+encodeURIComponent('title of page');

    window.open(facebook_url); 


});
```

Comment: encodeURIComponent should turn the http:// part into what you pasted. decodeURIComponent should unconvert it. How are you passing the URL to the Facebook sharer API?

Comment: That's exactly correct.  What problem are you having?

Comment: I updated my source code.

Comment: Your escapes are completely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it as simple as:

```
var facebook_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.site.com/folder1/' + findfb +'&title=' + 'title of page');
```

Answer (score 0):

`var facebook_url = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://www.site.com/folder1/' + findfb) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent('title of page');`