# In sharer.php , unable to acess the parameters passed with the url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-sharer

I am trying to open sharer.php as follows

> http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://mywebsite.com/index.php?var1=XYZ&var2=ABC

When share dialog opens , var1 is accessed in index.php but var2 is not accessible :(

But if i open

> http://mywebsite.com/index.php?var1=XYZ&var2=ABC

in new window , its easily accessible.

**Please help how can var2 be accessed , while using with sharer.php ?**

Answer (score 0):

Don´t forget to encode the URL, see the answer of this thread: [URL being encoded wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879356/url-being-encoded-wrong)

So you have to use `encodeURIComponent` to encode it:

```
var url = 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent('http://mywebsite.com/index.php?var1=XYZ&var2=ABC');
```